# Can't access network locations after editing windows 10 registry

Tags: windows, networking, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I wanted to remove the network icon from the Windows 10 explorer and in order to do that I read that I had to edit the windows registry I followed the steps in [this website](https://www.thepcinsider.com/remove-network-icon-windows-file-explorer/) also took ownership of the registry keys so I could add the new values to it.

The keys I edited were:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}
```

I only added "*System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree*" as a value to those two keys, after doing that the icon was gone but I couldn't access the network locations that I always use nor can I open or add/map any network location, I restored the keys to its original state of ownership deleted the new values I had added, the network icon is back now but it shows with a different name **"Network (32-bit)"** [New network icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYzop.png)

And still can't access any network location, if I click the icon nothing happens, I also used system restore and didn't help, I did reset all network settings too, network discovery is on in private and public profiles, latest updates installed, when trying to add/map, or access a shared drive or folder via "run" or windows explorer's address bar i get this screen:

[image: Error]

I still can print to shared and network printers and connect to local remote desktops, I hope someone here can help me fix this because I really don't want to reinstall or reset windows since I hace a lot of stuff installed..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. 

For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

Comment: too late to do that lol

Comment: Can you access the server using UNC path? I.E., Make a new shortcut and set it to `\\servername\shared_foldername`

Comment: I've tried that with no luck, can't create shortcuts to any network locations